# Configure upload folder on WoComerce

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I have a WordPress site with WooCommerce for my hobbie (painting) where users can upload their pics to ask me for paints.

Using the fileds of WooCommerce uploads, the plugin upload the user images to a path like this:

`wp-content/uploads/woocommerce_uploads/checkout_fields/files`

and that is a public folder.

Can the destination of this fields change in some way?

Comment: The uploads-folder is publicly accessible, since WordPress in it's core is used to make content to show to users (and all this webshop, form submissions, etc. is something that is built on top of that). Therefore WordPress (and WooCommerce) will always make uploads publically excessible, since it thinks: 'All uploads are meant to show to the users'. I would suggest trying and looking into finding a plugin that does what you want. I can't see a quick-fix to this, I'm sorry to say.

Comment: @Zeth, thanks for the explanation. Very sorry to see wp is so limited. Seems the plugging I am using is Flexible Checkout Fields, could it be tunning it up to deliver file in another folder?